# Combine user level and page in Big Query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I started exploring big query, i am wondering, is it possible to combine in big query or GA number of unique users and pages that they have seen?
So i want to see how many are there Y unique visitors who viewed one or more pages and of these, Z% also viewed W pages?

I used below query to get Y unique visitors who viewed certain pages, but not able to see the % who have viewed W pages.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
hits.page.pagePath AS other_seen_pages,
COUNT(hits.page.pagePath) AS number_other_seen_pages
FROM `project.dataset.session`,UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE fullVisitorId IN (
  SELECT fullVisitorId
  FROM `project.dataset.session`,UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE hits.page.pagePath LIKE '%x_page%'
  GROUP BY fullVisitorId )
AND hits.page.pagePath IS NOT NULL
AND hits.page.pagePath NOT LIKE '%x_page%'
GROUP BY other_seen_pages
ORDER BY number_other_seen_pages DESC;
```

Comment: could you provide an expected output example and an interpretation sentence for relevant numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you would like a query where, on top on the other pages that the same visitors visited, the number of visitors (from the same subset of visitors) that visited them (and the percentage above the total amount of users) appears.

Here is some code that worked for me with the `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` Google Analytics public table and the  '/google+redesign/electronics' pagePath:

It:

1. creates a table with the total number of different users in the table
2. creates a table like yours, with the addition of a filed for the total of different users that visited your page and the page of the row
3. selects the desired fields from these two tables and computes the %

.

```
WITH 
t_total_users as (select count(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) as total_users from `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`),

t_other_pages as (SELECT
hits.page.pagePath AS other_seen_pages,
COUNT(hits.page.pagePath) AS number_other_seen_pages,
COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorID) as visitors_per_page
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE fullVisitorId IN (
  SELECT fullVisitorId
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`,UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE hits.page.pagePath LIKE '/google+redesign/electronics'
  GROUP BY fullVisitorId )
AND hits.page.pagePath IS NOT NULL
AND hits.page.pagePath NOT LIKE '/google+redesign/electronics'
GROUP BY other_seen_pages
ORDER BY number_other_seen_pages DESC)

SELECT 
t_other_pages.other_seen_pages,
t_other_pages.number_other_seen_pages,
t_other_pages.visitors_per_page,
t_total_users.total_users,
(t_other_pages.visitors_per_page/t_total_users.total_users)*100 as percentage_visitants
FROM t_total_users, t_other_pages
```

If there is something in the query goal I missunderstood please specify!